# Vaadin 7 Buttons of SubWindow

Tags: java, vaadin7

On the page http://demo.vaadin.com/ReindeerTheme/ the Sub-Windows are resizable, with a min limit for width and height and without a fullSize Button.

I found no option to do the same with my Sub-Windows. With `setResizable(false)`, the fullSize Button is hidden, but the Window can't be resized.

Comment: Why would you use setResizable(false) when you want a resizable subwindow? (The "fullSize Button" must be a Vaadin 7 feature.) What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works on that page, but we can do a similar effect with CSS.

java:

```
Window window = new Window("Normal window");
window.setWidth("250px");
window.setHeight("180px");
window.addStyleName("my-window");
UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
```

css:

```
.v-window-my-window .v-window-maximizebox {
    display: none;
}
.v-window-my-window {
    min-width: 150px !important;
    min-height: 150px !important;
}
```

Comment: useless solution since it only hides the button but it can still be double clicked to do same effect